# React: Firefox opens and closes Pop-Up Window immediately

Tags: javascript, reactjs, popup, window

I have a problem with making a pop up window work in my React app. When the user presses a button in the app, a new window showing an image is supposed to appear. The image is retrieved from the backend and the window is provided with its URL (e.g. blob:http://localhost:3000/5aff23ae-...). However, when using Firefox, the window appears just for a short time (where the image is visible), and then immediately closes. I do not have these problems when using Chrome. If I hardcode the URL, for example as "http://www.google.com", the window stays visible in both browsers.

Can anyone tell me why the window is automatically closed and how to disable it?
I have already enabled Firefox to allow pop-up windows for localhost:3000, I'm using Firefox ver. 73.0.1.
This is the code for the button (I'm currently using material, but switching to a standard HTML button doesn't change anything):

```
<IconButton variant= "contained" color="secondary" className="clicked-button"
    onClick={()=>{
        Images.getImage(imagePath).then((result)=>{
            window.open(result.src, '', 'width=600,height=400,left=200,top=200')
        })
    }}

    ><ZoomInOutlinedIcon/></IconButton>
```

I appreciate any help!

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't reproduce your problem, can you provide more information? I'm using Firefox version 73.0.1

Comment: I have found the problem, it was an adblocker extension which I didn't consider. Disabling it for localhost solved the problem.